# Как упорядочить элементы по одному элементу в многомерном массиве и не только

Tags: java

Первые три строки после класса - поля, которые содержит класс Train. Как их использовать позже - не особо ясно. Но сейчас мне нужно другое, а именно:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Train {
    String name; //название пункта назначения
    int tnum;    //номер поезда
    Date time;   //время отправления

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int p = 5;
    Train train[] = new Train[p];
      train[0] = new Train("Москва", 122, "05:44");
      train[1] = new Train("Тюмень", 123, "07:45");
      train[2] = new Train("Санкт-Петербург", 124, "12:08");
      train[3] = new Train("Москва", 125, "12:42");
      train[4] = new Train("Оренбург", 126, "16:24");

}
```

У меня есть массив из пяти элементов типа train, мне нужно упорядочить элементы по номерам поездов(122, 123, 124, 125, 126). А после, при вызове этого номера через консоль, вывести информацию об этом поезде, т.е. достать всё из массива, условно вводим 124 и получаем:

```
Пункт назначения: Санкт-Петербург
Номер поезда: 124
Время отправления: 12:08
```

Как это можно сделать? Кстати, у меня почему-то ещё жалуется консоль на сам массив, может как-то не так оформил?

Comment: В гугле много говорят про java.util.Arrays, но я не особо понимаю, как его использовать

Answer (score 0):

Для сортировки объектов массива можно использовать [`Arrays::sort(T[] arr, Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-), в данном случае сортировка по номеру поезда может выглядеть так (при условии, что есть метод-геттер для поля `tnum`):

```java
Arrays.sort(train, Comparator.comparingInt(Train::getTnum));
```

Однако для быстрого доступа по номеру поезда массив не слишком подходящая структура данных, для этого больше подходит хэш-таблица (`Map`), хранящая набор пар "ключ-значение", таблица, отсортированная по ключу -- `TreeMap`:

```java
Map<Integer, Train> trainMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Train t : train) {
    trainMap.put(train.getTnum(), train);
}
```

Или же можно преобразовать массив в отсортированную таблицу при помощи Stream API, в частности, [`Collectors::toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```java
Map<Integer, Train> trainMap = Arrays.stream(train) // Stream<Train>
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Train::getTnum, // ключ: номер поезда
        t -> t,         // значение: экземпляр поезда
        (t1, t2) -> t1, // функция для разрешения конфликтов
        TreeMap::new    // Supplier<Map>
    ));
```

Comment: А как метод-геттер можно включить в данный массив? Для меня это что-то страшное и непонятное. Из того, что я вычитал и попробовал, он мне не даёт возможности сделать getTnum. Консоль говорит, что Не удается вызвать getTnum() в массиве типа Train[]...

Comment: Метод-геттер должен быть не в массиве, а в классе `Train`, он просто возвращает некоторое поле: `public int getTnum() { return tnum; }`